# Using variables created in a function that is defined in another file

Tags: python, function, file, variables

I have two .py files, let's say a.py and b.py. In a.py I have a bunch of functions, in these functions variables are created and declared as global:

```
def func1():
    
    global x

    x = 2

    return x
```

In b.py I want to use this function and later its variable, so I import the function:

```
from a.py import func1

func1()

add = 5 + x
```

When I do this I get the error; name 'x' not defined. Why do I get this error and how can I make this work?

I don't know how to make this work whatsoever as I thought "global [variable]" and "from [file] import [function]" would suffice. It did not.

Comment: You need to either `import a` (not "a.py") and then reference `a.x`, or do `from a import x`.

Comment: Since the function returns the value, why do you need the gloabl variable? Just use the function's value.

Comment: "in these functions variables are created and declared as global" that is a very bad practice that you should almost certainly avoid

Comment: In any case, `global` in python means *module level scope*. So if you `import a` then do `a.func1(); print(a.x)` you'll see what you want. What you are trying to do is absolutely not recommended, it is a well-known anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, global variables are (by definition) defined outside of functions. That said, can you do the following?

```
def func1():
    x = 2
    return x
```

```
from a.py import func1

x = func1()

add = 5 + x
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this at all!  But you can do:

```
$ cat a.py; echo
def func1(v):
    global x
    x = v

$ cat b.py; echo
#!/usr/bin/env python
import a
try: print(a.x)
except Exception as e: print(f"caught: {e}")
a.func1(3)
print(f'a.x = {a.x}')

$ PYTHONPATH=. ./b.py
caught: module 'a' has no attribute 'x'
a.x = 3
```

That is, if you try 'from a import x' before a.func1 is called, you will throw an Exception.  You could wrap the import in a try/except, but probably the better approach is to provide a value for x outside of any function so that you can do that import.  You could delay the import until after a.func1 is called, but it's a bit weird.  If for some reason you want to delay adding `x` to the namespace until `func1` is called, you just need to reference it as `a.x`.